# is it possible to stream a database table data using spark streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

Trying to stream SQLServer table data. So, Have created a simple java program with main class. Created a sparkconf and using that, initiated a JavaStreamingContext and retrieved SparkContext from it. Using JdbcRDD and JavaRDD of Spark APIs recieved the data from Database and initiated an inputQueue then prepared JavaInputDStream. So finished with the prerequisites and started the JavaStreamingContext. So am getting the first set of data which i received while preparing an inputQueue, but not getting the data for further streams.

`````
package com.ApacheSparkConnection.ApacheSparkConnection;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Queue;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;
import org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer;
import com.infosys.himi.maskit.algorithms.encryptiondecryption.EncryptionARC4;
import com.infosys.maskit.common.util.ConfigParams;

import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.reflect.ClassManifestFactory$;
import scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0;
import scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1;

public class MainSparkConnector {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String dbtableQuery = "SELECT TOP 10 AGENT_CODE,AGENT_NAME,WORKING_AREA,COMMISSION,PHONE_NO,COUNTRY FROM dbo.AGENTS where AGENT_CODE >= ? and AGENT_CODE <= ?";

        String host = "XXXXXXXXX";
        String databaseName = "YYYY";
        String user = "sa";
        String password = "XXXXXX@123";

        long previewSize = 0; 

        Instant start = Instant.now();

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJdbcDs")
                .setMaster("local[4]")
                .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");

        JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(10));
        JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext  =  javaStreamingContext.sparkContext();
        SparkContext sparkContext = javaSparkContext.sc(); 

        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://" + host + ":1433;databaseName=" + databaseName;
        String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"; 

        DbConnection dbConnection = new DbConnection(driver, url, user, password);

        JdbcRDD<Object[]> jdbcRDD =
                new JdbcRDD<Object[]>(sparkContext, dbConnection, dbtableQuery, 0,
                              100000, 10, new MapResult(), ClassManifestFactory$.MODULE$.fromClass(Object[].class));

        JavaRDD<Object[]> javaRDD = JavaRDD.fromRDD(jdbcRDD, ClassManifestFactory$.MODULE$.fromClass(Object[].class));

        List<String> employeeFullNameList = javaRDD.map(new Function<Object[], String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(final Object[] record) throws Exception {
                String rec = "";
                for(Object ob : record) {
                    rec = rec + " " + ob;
                }
                return rec;
            }
        }).collect();

        JavaRDD<String> javaRDD1 = javaStreamingContext.sparkContext().parallelize(employeeFullNameList);
        Queue<JavaRDD<String>> inputQueue = new LinkedList<JavaRDD<String>>();

        inputQueue.add(javaRDD1);

        JavaInputDStream<String> javaDStream = javaStreamingContext.queueStream(inputQueue, true);
        System.out.println("javaDStream.print()");
        javaDStream.print();
        javaDStream.foreachRDD( rdd-> {
            System.out.println("rdd.count() : "+ rdd.count());
            rdd.collect().stream().forEach(n-> System.out.println("item of list: "+n));
        });
        javaStreamingContext.start();

        System.out.println("employeeFullNameList.size() : "+employeeFullNameList.size());

        javaStreamingContext.awaitTermination();
    }

    static class DbConnection extends AbstractFunction0<Connection> implements Serializable {

        private String driverClassName;
        private String connectionUrl;
        private String userName;
        private String password;

        public DbConnection(String driverClassName, String connectionUrl, String userName, String password) {
            this.driverClassName = driverClassName;
            this.connectionUrl = connectionUrl;
            this.userName = userName;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public Connection apply() {
            try {
                Class.forName(driverClassName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to load driver class" +e);
            }

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("user", userName);
            properties.setProperty("password", password);

            Connection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, properties);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Connection failed"+ e);
            }

            return connection;
        }
    }

    static class MapResult extends AbstractFunction1<ResultSet, Object[]> implements Serializable {

        public Object[] apply(ResultSet row) {
            return JdbcRDD.resultSetToObjectArray(row);
        }
    }
}````
Please let me know if am in wrong direction
`````

Comment: Are you also looking to stream the subsequent changes done to database after your Spark streaming Job is started ?

Comment: want to stream the entire data again after spark streaming job started, so if there are any changes then it have to show with the entire data anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

Streaming  RDBMS's snaoshot of initial data via Spark Streaming is easy but there is no direct way of getting the trailing changes happening in DB.

Better solution would be go via a **Debezium SQL Server Connector**

> Debezium’s SQL Server Connector can monitor and record the row-level
>   changes in the schemas of a SQL Server database.

- You will need to setup a Kafka Cluster
- Enable CDC for SQL sever

SQL Server CDC is not designed to store the complete history of database changes. It is thus necessary that Debezium establishes the baseline of current database content and streams it to the Kafka. This is achieved via a process called snapshotting.

By default (snapshotting mode initial) the connector will upon the first startup perform an initial consistent snapshot of the database (meaning the structure and data within any tables to be captured as per the connector’s filter configuration).

Each snapshot consists of the following steps:

```
Determine the tables to be captured

Obtain a lock on each of the monitored tables to ensure that no structural changes can occur to any of the tables. The level of the lock is determined by snapshot.isolation.mode configuration option.

Read the maximum LSN ("log sequence number") position in the server’s transaction log.

Capture the structure of all relevant tables.

Optionally release the locks obtained in step 2, i.e. the locks are held usually only for a short period of time.

Scan all of the relevant database tables and schemas as valid at the LSN position read in step 3, and generate a READ event for each row and write that event to the appropriate table-specific Kafka topic.

Record the successful completion of the snapshot in the connector offsets.
```

Reading the change data tables

Upon first start-up, the connector takes a structural snapshot of the structure of the captured tables and persists this information in its internal database history topic. Then the connector identifies a change table for each of the source tables and executes the main loop

```
For each change table read all changes that were created between last stored maximum LSN and current maximum LSN

Order the read changes incrementally according to commit LSN and change LSN. This ensures that the changes are replayed by Debezium in the same order as were made to the database.

Pass commit and change LSNs as offsets to Kafka Connect.

Store the maximum LSN and repeat the loop.
```

After a restart, the connector will resume from the offset (commit and change LSNs) where it left off before.

The connector is able to detect whether the CDC is enabled or disabled for whitelisted source table during the runtime and modify its behavior.

The SQL Server connector writes events for all insert, update, and delete operations on a single table to a single Kafka topic. The name of the Kafka topics always takes the form serverName.schemaName.tableName, where serverName is the logical name of the connector as specified with the database.server.name configuration property, schemaName is the name of the schema where the operation occurred, and tableName is the name of the database table on which the operation occurred.

For example, consider a SQL Server installation with an inventory database that contains four tables: `products, products_on_hand, customers, and orders` in schema `dbo`. If the connector monitoring this database were given a logical server name of fulfillment, then the connector would produce events on these four Kafka topics:

```
    fulfillment.dbo.products
    fulfillment.dbo.products_on_hand
    fulfillment.dbo.customers

    fulfillment.dbo.orders
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
but this requirement is not restricted to SQLServer alone and also have to process billions of records. So is there any other way which best fits for this usecase ?

Comment: Debezium has connector for almost all Databases . If you want to stream billions of records followed by the Database changes in real time then Debezium + kafka + Spark is only way I can suggest.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you can provide any sample links in java, if you have it in handy ?

Comment: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/sqlserver.html

The effort is more on infra side and installing and use the existing tools in order to solve trivial problems we Data engineer faces from time to time